# Подключение sql плагинов к Qt приложению

Tags: плагин, qt, mysql

Qt 4.8.6.

Собрал плагин для MySQL.

Скопировал в папку с приложением `libmysql.dll`, `qsqlmysql4.dll`.

В папке `%QT_PATH/plugins/sqldrivers` есть `qsqlmysql4.dll`, `qsqlmysql4.a`, `qsqlmysql4d.dll`, `qsqlmysql4d.a`.

Выполняю такой код:

```
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
```

Получаю

```
("SQLITE", "QODBC3", "QODBC")
```

Т.е. плагин не подключился. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Скопируйте плагины в папку sqldrivers рядом с приложением.

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. Положил в sqldrivers и в plugins/sqldrivers.
    
    qDebug() << QApplication::libraryPaths();

Вывод:
    
    ("C:/Qt/Qt-4.8.6/plugins", "C:/projects/test_mysql/release")

В C:/Qt/Qt-4.8.6/plugins есть папка sqldrivers в ней лежат qsqlmysql4.dll и libqsqlmysql4.a. Видимо, дело не в путях.

Comment: А если добавить путь C:/projects/test_mysql/release/sqldrivers в QApplication::libraryPaths()?

Comment: Попробовал. Безрезультатно.
Может проблема с версиями Mysql Connector/C 6.1.5, Qt 4.8.6?

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Прочитайте раздел справки Qt http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#creating-the-application-package, там все написано. В Вашем случае библиотеки 'qsqlmysql4.dll' и 'qsqlmysql4d.dll' положить в 'C:/projects/test_mysql/release/sqldrivers', а вот библиотеку 'libmysql.dll' рядом с приложением. Успехов!